# Bash Script Block All Apple Devices

Tags: linux, bash, iptables, nmap

I am trying to create a shell script to block all apple devices on my network. I am using `nmap` for os detection. What I have so far is this:

```
while (true) do
    nmap -O -T4 -p 22,80 -v 172.20.0.0/24 | grep -B9 'OS details: Apple' | \
        grep 'Nmap scan report for' | cut -f4 -d'r' | cut -f2 -d' ' | \
        iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT -j DROP -s
    sleep 10
done
```

Is there a way to simplify this at all so there is less grepping and cutting involved?
Also, this script will run into errors if there are more than one or zero apple devices found on the network. Is it possible to add logic for that?

Comment: Does iptables read addresses from stdin?

Comment: This is **not** off-topic, just because the word 'network' appears. It's still a reasonable question about bash programming / logic.

Comment: This is an awesome idea. I think I'll use this trick on my non-tech friends. Then I can flaunt my android device. (Evil laughter) :)

Comment: @alvits It would have to be run on a gateway or on a device that has somehow become the man in the middle. `iptables` will only affect traffic passing through your device. You could use arp cache poisoning or dhcp spoofing (see dsploit for android) to get their traffic to pass through you, but then that would be more of a topic for the info sec forums I suppose :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course it is possible. You can use perl/awk to simplify the script a lot.

Also, I'm not sure that your script is correct at the moment.
You have a pipe that write addresses to iptables, but `iptables` 
doesn't work this way.

If you want to run `iptables` for each address that is produced by `nmap`,
you can read the addresses using `read` to some variable (in my example `ADDR`)
and then use the variable in `iptables`:

```
while (true) do
    nmap -O -T4 -p 22,80 -v 172.20.0.0/24 | grep -B9 'OS details: Apple' | \
        grep 'Nmap scan report for' | cut -f4 -d'r' | cut -f2 -d' ' | \
        while read ADDR
        do
          iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT -j DROP -s $ADDR
        done
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: What if I enclosed the address in ` symbols?

Comment: @735Tesla: It is better to use `while/read` in this case. Please see my update

Comment: @735Tesla: `ADDR` can't be null, because in this case the loop body inside do/done will not be executed. Read will retrun false in this case.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help! Could you point me towards a resource that may help me learn the skills I need to simplify this a bit?

Comment: Yes. I would recommend this: [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: Please, please avoid citing this reference.  The official manual is a pretty good reference.

Comment: @devnull: Why? You don't like this reference?

Comment: Yes, there are several inaccuracies in the one you've referred.  It's one of those references that are probably best to avoid.  YMMV.

Comment: @devnull: Could you please point me at these inaccuracies, so I could know why I avoid the reference?

Answer (score 2):

A few more remarks:

- You do not need the parenthesis around `true`. This starts a new subshell, which is inefficient. In this case, you probably won't care, but it's good practice to avoid needless subshells.
- the `$ADDR` in [Igor Chubin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20886794/1183387) is dangerous. If `$ADDR` contains a whitespace character, it will be split up into separate parameters. Someone on the network may be able to affect the output of NMap, and modify the structure of the iptables command. Even if this is not the case here, it's good practice to put the argument in between double quotes whenever possible to prevent this: `"$ADDR"`.
- for similar reasons, you'll usually want to use `read -r` instead of just `read`. Without the `-r` parameter, backslash characters in the input will escape subsequent special characters (such as spaces).
- NMap has its own Lua scripting support. This is another way to go at this problem, which may relieve you from having to parse any text at all.
- If you are physically on the same network, you may be able to block Apple devices without any NMap at all, by blocking devices based on the MAC address of the device. The first three bytes identify the organisation which issued the MAC address. You can look them up [here](http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt). They can be faked on a rooted device, but then again, so can the NMap fingerprinting (though that would likely be harder).

Answer (score 1):

An important part of scripting is understanding the programs you are using and how to get the appropriate output from them. It looks like you have a decent understanding of Nmap, since you limit the number of ports scanned (`-p 22,80`) and request OS detection (`-O`), but you could avoid a lot of text processing if you used the [appropriate output format](http://nmap.org/book/man-output.html).

Nmap's "grepable" format is deprecated, meaning that it can't be used to get a lot of more-recent features' output, but it works just fine for OS detection. You request it with `-oG`. Here's an example, borrowing some looping help from [@IgorChubin's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20886794/1183387):

```
while (true) do
    nmap -O -T4 -p 22,80 -oG - 172.20.0.0/24 | awk '/OS: Apple/{print $2}' | \
        while read ADDR
        do
          iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT -j DROP -s $ADDR
        done
    sleep 10
done
```

Some other improvements include moving the `sleep 10` into the `while` condition of the outermost loop, to allow killing it with Ctrl-C during one of the sleeps. Also, be aware that DHCP leases expire, and the IP you are blocking may be assigned to a different system in the future. In general, this approach does not seem like the best way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks this wasn't going to be something I used much anyway. More for annoying friends and family and the like. `-oG` is really useful thanks for the tip! +1